# I have passed an array in session variable. I need to pass key strokes to it to return values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

I have stored the returned data from a mysql query into a session variable.  I can extract what I want from using `$_SESSION['info'][][]`.

I would like to be able to retrieve values from the array dynamically.  The user will select numbers from drop downs (2 of them). One of the numbers needs to passed to the first element of the array and obviously, the second goes to the second element. And then, the result is echoed to the screen.

I need to do this all client side. So like this:

- Get result of keypress a
- Store it as $a
- Get the result of keypress b
- Store it as $b
- Pass the results of to `echo $_SESSION['info'][$a][$b]`

I can get one key stroke and pass it to a variable and even possible the second with my limited knowledge but pass them to the session variable and printing the result escapes me at the moment.

```
enter code here$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#pcc").keyup(function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val();
    $n1=dInput;

    //$(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pcp").keyup(function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val();
    $n2=dInput

    //$(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
    });
```

});

I know I could probably nest that but one hurdle at a time.  I know that saves the keystrokes.  I have tested it by passing the values to alerts.

Progess at last.  I am using this code to pass the variables from the input fields:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#pcp").keyup(function(){
    var value = $("#pcp").val();
    n1= value;

      });
      $("#pcp").keyup(function(){
      var value = $("#pcc").val();
      n2= value;

     matrix('n1','n2');
    });

   });
```

And I know its getting passed to matrix() because Im dumping the variables to console from within matrix like so:

```
      function matrix(){
    // getting values from key presses

    //console.log(n1, n2);
     $.ajax({
    url: "matrix.php",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { a: n1, b: n2 },
    success: function(data) {

      var response = data.response;
}

     $_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix'][$a][$b]= response;

       });
```

I also know that the variables have been passed because I was getting variable undefined errors in console and now I dont.  So 2 positive things. 
However, thats as far as seem to be able to go. I dont seem to be getting anything back.  I have tried putting console.log inside of matrix.php but I dont get anything in that either so Im guessing its just not firing and sending data to matrix.php.  Is there any other testing I can do to see where its failing?  I feel that Im close to nailing it.

};

Comment: Edit the codes you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is AJAX. You need to create a PHP script that will take two values for `$a` and `$b` through a `GET` or `POST` request. You can then use jQuery's `$.ajax` to asynchronously invoke that script and get the result.

So for a start you need a PHP script (let's call it for the sake of this example: **example.php**).

In **example.php** you can do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$a = $_GET['var_a'];
$b = $_GET['var_b'];
//do some checking of the two above variables here
$response = array(
    'response' => $_SESSION['info'][$a][$b];
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

You can substitude `$_POST` with `$_GET` if you prefer using a `POST` request instead.

The next step involves quite a bit of JavaScript so, when you have both $n1 and $n2 populated you can send a POST request using `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: <path-to-example.php>,
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
    data: { var_a: $n1, var_b: $n2 }
}).done(function(data){
    var response = data.response;
    //$_SESSION['info'][$a][$b] is now in response
});
```

Again you can substitute `'get'` with `'post'` in case of a `POST` request

Comment: Am I on the right track here?  At the moment I am just trying to capture one keypress and pass it across.  I just want to make sure I am actually triggering the json call and getting a response (at the moment I dont care if its the wrong response (baby steps)). So in my little pea brain this what Ive done,  Looked for a key up or change in the element id=pcp, passed its value to n1 and then because the ajax call is nested inside the key up event the value gets passed across.  Well thats the theory.  Does it work.NO! I am not sure I getting the value of #pcp even.

Comment: $("#pcp").on("keyup change",(function(){
        var n1 =this.value;
               alert(n1);
    
       );
    
        $.ajax({
        url: <matrix.php>,
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
        data: { a: n1 }
    
      }).done(function(data){
    var response = data.response;
    //$_SESSION['info'][$a][$b] is now in response
      });  
       }

Comment: @AdrianFischer What's in your PHP script? Also have you tried `console.log(response);` to see what's in the response?

Comment: this is my php file.  I have print_r'd the response and its empty.  Using firebug I can see the response headers so its getting there and back but its not returning anything.  I can also see the POST has set the variables.  It shows me parameters  and source and they match so Im guessing thats a good thing.  So I think it must be my php script.                           <?php
session_start();
$a = $_POST['var_a'];
$b = $_POST['var_b'];


$response = array('response' => $_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix']['$a']['$b']);
json_encode($response);

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
$a = $_POST['var_a'];
$b = $_POST['var_b'];


$response = array('response' => $_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix']['$a']['$b']);
json_encode($response);`

Comment: @AdrianFischer There could be something wrong with the session. Where is `$_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix']` set?

Comment: session is set elsewhere.  If I actually disregard the posted variables (and Im not sure they are actually getting there.  If I try to echo them out I get nothing), so if I manually put numbers in SESSION to replace the varialbles and then call it, it returns the desired result. So somehow, the variables are not getting inserted into SESSION as they should

Comment: Oh I understand. It seems that I might have made a mistake with the variable names. I edited my post. Check this JavaScript part: 

`data: { var_a: $n1, var_b: $n2 }`. Change `a` to `var_a` and `b` to `var_b` to match the indices you use in PHP

Comment: I can now echo the variables so I know they have been passed.  But they are not making it into the Session variable.  Almost there.

Comment: In the PHP code you posted earlier there are single quotes around the variable names: `$_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix']['$a']['$b']);`. Remove the single quotes and it should work:
`$_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix'][$a][$b]);`

Comment: Winner Winner , chicken dinner!!  Its taken me a couple of days to get here but here we are.  Learned heaps along the way too.. Thanks for you patience.  One final question.  I need to take on of those variables and add the letters RM to the front of it so it would become RM1 etc.  I cant put the letters RM in the session variable and just plonk the $b variable next to it so I need to add it outside the session and then add a new varialble in the session that has the RM and number together.  Sounds easy but I cant find any examples (yet).

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You mean that on of your variables, say $a, has the value 1 and you want to make it RM1 inside the `$_SESSION`? If that is the case you can easily achieve this by using double quotes (single quotes will not work) like this:`$_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix']["RM$a"]["RM$b"]`

Comment: Well you could have knocked me over with feather.  Thanks again

Comment: sorry to be a pest @dimlucas but I now cant get the response to display in my form.  The id of the element where I want it displayed is riskPostLevel and this is what Ive tried but I dont think Im using the right syntax to get the whats in the variable response.   `var response = data.response;
       console.log(response);
       $("#riskPostLevel").val(response.riskPostLevel);`

Comment: ended up working out I could get the info using this:  $('#riskPostLevel').val(data.response);

Comment: @AdrianFischer Glad you found it